# Reset counter automatically after 4 times

Tags: javascript

I built a counter but I do not manage to automatically reset counter if value = 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span class="hits"> 0 </span>
<button onclick="resetHits()" class="tryagain">RESTART</button>

<script>
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector('.hits');
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 32) {addHit()}}
var addHit = function() {hits++; renderHits()}
var renderHits = function() {hitElement.innerHTML = hits}
var resetHits = function() {hits = 0; renderHits()}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you expecting it to automatically reset the hits value to 0 when it reaches 4?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: `hits = (hits + 1) % 4;`

Comment: then add onkeyup check `if(hits === 4) resetHits();`

Comment: Thanks guys but could you please provide an answer which repeats my initial code? Because otherwise I do not fully understand where to place it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris suggested, `hitElement.innerHTML = hits % 5`

```js
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector(".hits");
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    addHit();
  }
};
var addHit = function () {
  hits++;
  renderHits();
};
var renderHits = function () {
  hitElement.innerHTML = hits %= 5;
  console.log({hits});
};
var resetHits = function () {
  hits = 0;
  renderHits();
};
```

```html
<span class="hits"> 0 </span>
<button onclick="resetHits()" class="tryagain">RESTART</button>
```

Update: Based on @tarkh's point, Updated to `hitElement.innerHTML = hits %= 5;`, So that variable value also upto date.

Comment: While this is working visually, be careful about `hits` value! It is not resets automatically and keeps counting...

Comment: @tarkh, That's good point. Just updated to use as ```hits %= 5``` to fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 4 will not be displayed. It will reset to 0 automatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span class="hits"> 0 </span>
<button onclick="resetHits()" class="tryagain">RESTART</button>

<script>
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector('.hits');
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 32) {addHit()}}
var addHit = function() {
   hits++; 
   if (hits === 4) {
     resetHits();
   }
   renderHits()
}
var renderHits = function() {hitElement.innerHTML = hits}
var resetHits = function() {hits = 0; renderHits()}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I modifying your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span class="hits"> 0 </span>
<button onclick="resetHits()" class="tryagain">RESTART</button>

<script>
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector('.hits');
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    // ADD counter check here
    if(hits === 4 + 1) { // Add +1 if you need do reset after 4 displayed
      // Do what you want  
      resetHits();
    }
    // Then it depends on your logic,
    // if you don't need to cycle counter immediately,
    // add rest to else condition like so
    else { addHit(); }
  }
}
var addHit = function() {hits++; renderHits()}
var renderHits = function() {hitElement.innerHTML = hits}
var resetHits = function() {hits = 0; renderHits()}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```